# How can user download the image to their mobile gallery?

Tags: php, mobile, safari, mobile-website

Here is my code,

```
<?php
$file_name = "coupon.png";
$file_path = $_GET['path'];
$file_size = filesize($file_path);
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i ') . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private', false);
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: ' . $file_size);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name . '";');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
readfile($file_path);
?>
```

P.S. `$_GET['path']` for image path url

In PC's browser, Those coding can run smoothly.
However if user use their mobile browser to download, it will display a new web page tab.

Is there any way that user can download the image and store into their mobile gallery automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<?php
$file_name = "coupon.png";
$file_path = $_GET['path'];
$file_size = filesize($file_path);
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i ') . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private', false);
header('Content-Type: application/force-download'); // Browser cant identifiy the type. so it will force to download
header('Content-Length: ' . $file_size);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name . '";');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
readfile($file_path);
?>
```

because the mobile browser doesn't know how to open the file, so it forced to download.